# TCP sockets and port occupancy

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

How do you communicate with a remote **Server**, who will always send his answer packages to your requests, to the IP/Port Tuple the requests come from ?

In **TCP** you will always need two sockets. One for the local **Server** and one for the local **Client**. As it is not possible to bind them to exactly the same port, let's say i bind the **Server** socket to port ***X*** and the **Client** socket to port ***Y***. Now sending a request with the help of my local **Client** to the remote server, would cause that the remote **Server** respectively now the remote **Client** sends his answer to port ***Y***, but my local Server is listening on Port ***X***.

Neither i can use a single socket for sending and receiving, like in **UDP**, nor i can bind twice the same port.

Comment: Why do you need a local Server? If you are connecting to a remote Server you just create a local Client that sends request and handles writes on the socket. Look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) example from socket documentation

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you talking about this: "data = s.recv(1024)" in my local Client ? I thought this would be a simple ack for my request if the remote server's response is in there this would solve my problem, i didn'nt mention that.

Comment: Yes the response would be written on the same socket. And you can read it using `recv()`

Comment: This would totally solve my problem. I will give it a try as soon as possible. If it works for me you could maybe write an answer so i can mark this thread to be solved by your answer. I appriciate your help. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a local Server. The client can send and receive data to/from the Server over the same socket.

Check out examples in [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) documentation and example of a client in the [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example) documentation